# The word "perplexed" in academic writing

Tags: academia

Can I use the word "perplexed" in academic writing? If not, would you please suggest another word?

Example sentence: When numerical examples provide different results, audience will be left perplexed on how the issue is solved.

Comment: Why couldn't you? It's proper English, not informal, and not rude or a colloquialism. Is there a reason you believe it to be inappropriate?

Comment: Context please, eg sample sentence.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I usually search the literature I have if I am not sure about a specific word. However, I only found one academic article in my database that used the word "perplexed", hence, I wasn't sure of using it.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I added an example sentence to the question.

Comment: You can also leave  the "audience" out and say "Examples which yield different results will be **perplexing**".   That is, they will perplex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can use *perplexed* or *confused* (or other synonyms), you may wish to consider terms such as *[un/clear](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unclear)* or *[un/certain](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/uncertain)* as well. These are more objective, in that they simply carry the meaning of a lack of understanding (clarity, certainty), and they thus lend themselves well to academic writing. Choose your words around whatever term you select, though - *an audience may be left with a lack of clarity or understanding* is less judgemental than *could confuse an audience*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think one can use *perplex* in academic writing but to make it sound better you can use ***confuse***.

More than using a different word, I think you can change the sentence construction to make it sound more *academic*.

"*Numerical examples providing different results can be confusing and would make issue too complex to be solved.*"